# 2+2=4, 6+5=11 and 6+7=1

Tags: riddle

There is something daily that works, truly, with the follow logic: 2+2=4, 6+5=11 and 6+7=1. Can you guess what it is?

Comment: Welcome to the site! Rot13: Vf vg fbzrguvat nf fvzcyr nf zbqhyb 12 nevguzrgvp? N qnvyl rknzcyr jbhyq or gur ubhef bs gur qnl be gur zbaguf bs gur lrne. If so, I'm not sure this really qualifies as a puzzle. Also, did you really ask everyone at your Uni? ;)

Comment: This is actually a pretty classic puzzle, I'm sure it's been asked several times here.

Comment: @Anon University Not at all, but at least 20 people from teachers and students in exact sciences... you know... a bunch of smart people... i'm kinda exaggerate in my speech but only to spice up things ;P

Comment: [logical-deduction] is for puzzles that require pure logical deduction, like Sudoku or logic grid puzzles. I think [tag:riddle] is appropriate here? It's not perfect, but this *is* giving "clues about an object to be identified"...

Comment: @Deusovi I think you are right... i just don`t see the tag when i do it, changed.

Answer (score 4):

This seems like it should've been asked before here, but I can't find the duplicate...

The answer is

> a clock, where 2 hours after 2 is 4, 5 hours after 6 is 11, and 7 hours after 6 is 1.